# Enabling wi-fi for an Optiplex 960?

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, router, wifi-configuration, dell-optiplex

The wired ethernet is working but I have problems turning on the wi-fi for some reason.

[image]

[image]

Why can't I use the Wi-Fi network with this Dell Optiplex 960? I put in the correct password and the Wi-Fi is working with other devices. I connect with ethernet cable to the cable modem, but it's supposed to work with wi-fi which works for 2/3 clients but not this. I use Windows 8.1 and it can see the network name but not connect. The WiFi adapter says it's an Intel WiFi Link in device manager.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the specs of that system, it does not have a wireless card or capability. If you added a card, Go to device manager to see if the PC recognizes it.

If you do not have wireless, a USB wireless adapter will get you where you need to go.

Wireless is nice, but wired is always the best option for stationary systems.

Comment: Device manager says it has Intel WiFi link 5300 AGN and it lists the WiFi network in a scan. But perhaps i put in the wrong password? I think it would be nice to get rid of a long cable. The wired ethernet is working but it should be possible to enable the WiFi.

Comment: Do you have the latest driver? I seen the PC does have the capability as an add on.

Comment: I just updated everything from Windows update and I still get the connection failure. I might try and download a spec driver for Windows 8.1 but I think that the driver is reporting that the WiFi adapter is working since it appears in device manager like it's working. I'll also try and reenter the correct password as weel as entering a faulty password to see if there is a difference. Any more ideas how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Remove the device and restart the PC, let the hardware reinstall itself. I take it there is no wireless icon in the task bar? Make sure your IP address is different than the others, but you should be getting a prompt about that.